# PHP Possibility to get PDF Color Separation List

Tags: php, pdf, colors

I'm trying to get a list of the color-separations of my uploaded PDF.
(to proceed a shop order).

I've tried with image Magick like this:

```
$im = new Imagick('mypdf.pdf');

$exifArray = $im->getImageProperties();

foreach ($exifArray as $name => $property)
{

        echo "{$name} => {$property}<br />\n";

}
```

But i've only received the Pantone Spot Colors. 
What when the PDF uses the colors PANTONE Orange 021 and CYAN?